# フォーカスしてフォントサイズを変えると他とliの位置が変化するのを直したい

Tags: html, css

フォーカスしてフォントサイズを変えると他とliの位置が変化しますがこれをどうにか一律に揃えたいです
vertical-alignとtext-alignを試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした
なので何か別の原因だと思いますが調べてもわかりませんでした

```css
ul {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  background-color: #1ab2fa;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

li:focus {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=-1>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>総合</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` プロパティの**初期値は `baseline`** であり、このプロパティでは**継承が行われません**。そのため、文字の下部はテキストのベースラインに合わせられており、 `ul` 要素の `vertical-align` プロパティは、これらの `li` 要素に影響を及ぼしません。

この問題を解決するためには、直接 `li` 要素に対して `vertical-align` プロパティを適用する必要があります。また、今回の場合 `ul` 要素への `vertical-align` プロパティの指定は不要です。

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  background-color: #1ab2fa;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* 移動 */
}

li:focus {
  background-color: #bb2a3f;
  font: 25px bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=-1>新着</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>月間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>週間</li>
  <li tabindex=-1>総合</li>
</ul>
```